# Workaround for the precision limitation for Python's round() function

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm trying to come up with a *general* way to correctly round floats with Python, given the known [limitation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) of `round()`:

> **Note**: The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for more information.

I thought that a simple way to correct for this effect is to add a small value to every float that ends with a `5`, like so:

```
a = 7.85
b = a + 0.001
round(b, 1)
> 7.9
```

Below is the function I've written to do this. I've tested it and it seems to work fine, but I'd like some input on possible caveats I might be overlooking (or ways to improve it)

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal
from random import randint


def floats_5(N):
    """
    Generate random floats between a random range, where all floats
    end with a '5'.
    """
    rang = randint(1, 10000)
    flts = np.random.uniform(-1.*rang, 1.*rang, N)

    # Add '5' to the end of each random float, with different lengths.
    fl_5 = []
    for f in flts:
        # Trim float.
        i = randint(2, len(str(f).split('.')[1]))
        # Create trimmed float that ends with a '5' .
        f = Decimal(str(f).split('.')[0] + '.' + str(f).split('.')[1][:i] +
                    '5')
        fl_5.append(f)

    return fl_5


def format_5(f):
    """
    Take float and add a decimal '1' to the end of it.

    Return the number of decimal paces and the new float.
    """
    # Count number of decimal places.
    n = len(str(f).split('.')[1])

    # Decimal '1'  to add to the end of the float.
    d = '0.' + '0'*n + '1'

    # Add or subtract depending on the sign of the float.
    c = -1. if str(f)[0] == '-' else 1.

    # New augmented float.
    new_float = f + Decimal(c)*Decimal(d)

    # Return number of decimals and float with the small value added.
    return n, new_float


# Get some random floats.
fl_5 = floats_5(10)

# Compare float, round(float), and round(new_float)
print 'Original   round(f)   round(new_f)'
for f in fl_5:
    n, new_float = format_5(f)
    print f, round(f, n-1), round(new_float, n-1), '\n'
```

Comment: After you are satisfied with this code, please take a look at the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for actual production usage.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `round(f, n)` (where `f` is the float and `n` is the number of digits to round to) with `Decimal`?

Comment: That's why I suggested to read it. Take a look at the `quantize` method and the description of rounding modes and the context.

Answer (score 4):

Following ferada's advice I looked up the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module and it simplifies things quite a bit.

This is a function that does what `format_5()` does but much succinctly:

```
def format_5_dec(f):
    new_float = Decimal.quantize(f, Decimal(str(f)[:-1]), rounding='ROUND_UP')
    return new_float
```

Comment: And you can even return directly: `return Decimal.quantize(f, Decimal(str(f)[:-1]), rounding='ROUND_UP')`

Comment: I don't like direct returns, I prefer expressing things I calculate as variables first. It makes things more explicit I think. Old habit from Fortran perhaps...

Comment: I don't like intermediate variables. I prefer expressing things I calculate as expressions only. It makes things more concise and to-the-point I think. Old habit from Python/Ruby/Haskell perhaps...